# Making sqlite3 inserts using python variable

Tags: variables, python-3.x, sqlite, insert, fill

so I have a sqlite3 table with the following schema:

```
('number','name','prename','id','number_a','location_num','team')
```

Im wondering how to be able to fill some of those with content of a python variable.Number,id,number_a and team dont have to be filled.So basically, I have 3 python variable

```
thename='franco'
theprename='john'
thelocation_num=2
```

So I want to be able to insert at the right place the content of the python variable.I tried this so far:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO mytable('number','name','prename','id','number_a','location_num','team') VALUES('','?','?','','','?','')",(thename,),(theprename,),(thelocation_num,))
```

However it doesnt work.I dont know how to do that.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO mytable
('number','name','prename','id','number_a','location_num','team')
VALUES('',?,?,'','',?,'')""",
(thename, theprename, thelocation_num))
```

If autocommit is not enabled, you also need to call `connection.commit()` in order to write the changes to disk.

Comment: I get error Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 3 supplied.

Comment: sorry, the placeholders should not be quoted, i.e., the question marks in the VALUES part must not be in quotes, otherwise they are treated as strings. Edited the answer.